# App Engine problems using the command line

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, command-line, google-cloud-datastore

I am developing an App Engine project on Windows using Eclipse and Python 2.5 and Django 0.96. Everything in my app, including Django, is working nicely.

My problems arise when I try to use command line. For example, I'm told that if I want to clear the local datastore I can enter "python manage.py reset" but when I do so the response is "python: can't open file 'manage.py'".

I feel as if I have missed a configuration step. I have checked my system variables and "Path" includes "C:\Python25" (which I had added manually) but nothing Django or App Engine related. My .py extension is associated with C:\Python25\python.exe.

In my quest to solve this, and in trying to understand what manage.py is, I see that I might have had to create a Django project using "django-admin.py startproject [myproject]" but because everything works nicely from Eclipse I'm not sure if this is necessary now. In any case, if I try to enter this from the command line I get "'django-admin.py' is not recognized..."

Please, what am I missing?

Comment: Make sure you are in your django app directory when attempting to call manage.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Django 0.96 templates within a 'normal' App Engine app, then `manage.py` isn't involved at all.

`/path/to/dev_appserver.py --clear_datastore .`

is what you want, assuming you're CD'd to the root of your app.

Comment: any version of django for that matter

Comment: Well, Django 0.96 is a good indication that something like Django-nonrel isn't in the picture.

Comment: correct, just saying manage.py is useless for appengine. i sometimes use gae and wish the django shell was available :(

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear and complete answer. The purpose of manage.py puzzles me, however. I have the Kindle edition of "Programming Google App Engine" by Dan Sanderson (O'Reilly) and he makes no fewer than 33 references to manage.py. Do I simply ignore all that? Does it have to do with my Django version?

Comment: I tracked down a copy of Sanderson's book. On page 318 he mentions that the `manage.py` he's talking about comes from `http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-django/`. If you go there, you'll see the warning

"As of Nov 2010, this helper is no longer the recommended way to run Django projects on Google App Engine."

followed by a link that'll give you info on replacements.